# Fast filtering over Bounded Enum type

Tags: haskell, optimization, enums

Let's say I have a function that takes some predicate f and applies it to the whole domain:

```
someFilter :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => (a -> Bool) -> [a]
someFilter f = filter f [minBound ..]
```

I also know that this predicate f returns True only for a relatively small number of arguments, e.g.

```
isA c = (c == 'A')
```

Is it possible to somehow make someFilter fast, i.e. not dependent on the number of possible values of type a, without changing its signature?

Comment: Not with the standard `filter`, I don't think.  You would need some way to inspect the predicate to determine if the search space can be reduced.  The best way would be to make a data type that represents predicates, then you could have something like `someFilter :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => Pred a -> [a]`.

Comment: Without any assumption on `f`, no general optimization seems possible. Checking whether there is an element in `[0..n]` satisfying a given (polytime) predicate `f` is NP-hard, so ...

Comment: Yeah, I know that in general it's not possible, but I was hoping I could achieve that implementing both someFilter and a predicate in some specific way and without guarantee for any other cases. Thanks!

Comment: In the specific case of checking for equality (and some other cases), if you know that you are operating on an ascending list (such as a list of the form `[a..]`, as in this case) and you add an `Ord` requirement (which I imagine would still fit most cases, since we already have `Bounded` and `Enum`) you could stop filtering after we reach a value greater than the value being compared against (here, `'A'`). Without more information about the specific problem being solved though, I don't think you can do much better.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really do this in general, since all you've given the function is that `a` is `Enum` and `Bounded`, which means you'd never be able to tell if the predicate even used `==` (not that you can do this anyway).  Instead, you can write a custom data type that can be inspected before performing the filter:

```
import Control.Applicative

infixr 2 `Or`
infixr 3 `And`
data Pred a
    = LessThan a
    | GreaterThan a
    | EqualTo a
    | Generic (a -> Bool)
    | And (Pred a) (Pred a)
    | Or  (Pred a) (Pred a)

someFilter :: (Enum a, Bounded a, Ord a) => Pred a -> [a]
someFilter p = go p [minBound ..]
    where
        go :: (Enum a, Bounded a, Ord a) => Pred a -> [a] -> [a]
        go (LessThan x)    = takeWhile (< x)
        go (GreaterThan x) = dropWhile (<= x)
        go (EqualTo x)     = const [x]
        go (Generic f)     = filter f
        go (And p q)       = go q . go p
        go (Or  p q)       = (++) <$> go p <*> go q

naiveFilter :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => (a -> Bool) -> [a]
naiveFilter f = filter f [minBound ..]
```

This gives you most of the tools you need (not all of them, this is just a rough outline) to recreate basic boolean combinations of ordering predicates with support for generic predicates.  For certain cases `someFilter` will perform much, much better than `naiveFilter`, such as for `someFilter (LessThan 128) :: [Word32]` versus `naiveFilter (< 128) :: [Word32]`.  On my computer the former finishes in essentially 0s, while the latter I didn't even let run to completion.  You can also run queries like `someFilter (And (LessThan 128) (GreaterThan 256)) :: [Word32]` that finish immediately, but would take forever with `naiveFilter`.  I've used `Word32` instead of `Int` here to avoid the problem of negative numbers.

If you want to combine a bunch of predicates together you can do

```
allPs, anyPs :: [Pred a] -> Pred a
allPs = foldr1 And
anyPs = foldr1 Or
```

Or you could try building a balanced tree out of it, but this will suffice for simplicity.  It does let you express rather complicated queries fairly easy:

```
> :set +s
> someFilter $ EqualTo 1 `Or` EqualTo 100 `Or` LessThan 1000 `And` GreaterThan 975 :: [Word32]
[1,100,976,977,978,979,980,981,982,983,984,985,986,987,988,989,990,991,992,993,994,995,996,997,998,999]
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
```

Be warned that order of operations matters here because of `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`, and you can also end up with duplicates (try making a greater-than-or-equals and less-than-or-equals, you'll see what I mean).  These fixes will start to eat at the performance of this algorithm, but in general you should see no worse performance than `naiveFilter`.

Comment: Wow! That's really elaborate. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `a` being [`Word160`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/largeword-1.2.3/docs/Data-LargeWord.html#t:Word160) and `f` being `(== w) . sha1` for a fixed word `w :: Word160`, where `sha1 :: Word160 -> Word160` is some implementation of [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1). Then the predicate is true only for a very small number of inputs (most likely 1). If you had a fast way how to find matching values, you'd be constructing an inverse function to SHA-1, which would allow you to crack digital signatures and all sorts of similar stuff. So no, there is no efficient way how to do this, unless you restrict the predicate somehow.